# Is it allowed to have the wedding dinner before the ceremony?

Tags: halacha, wedding, meal-seudah

In all Jewish weddings that I have attended the actual wedding (Chuppah and kiddushin) precedes the dinner (seudat mitzvah).

Do the sources speak about having the dinner **before** the ceremony. I was recently invited to such a wedding.

The following not insuperable problems occur to me:
chatan and kallah normally fast before the wedding so they would not eat at the meal;
since they are not married yet, there would be no sheva berachot after the birkat hamazon.

Comment: Interesting question. For clarity, wouldn't the smorg be considered a "meal"? Most people eat more at the smorg than at the sit down meal, anyway. And most smorgs are before the chuppah. How would THAT be allowed based on your question?

Comment: If the family of the chatan is Sephardi, then they likely won't fast before, I believe that that custom is unique to Ashkenazi Jewry.